# Make a mesh unprintable, but still viewable with three.js

Tags: three.js, mesh

Is there a way to make a mesh unprintable with a 3D printer, but still viewable with three.js.

Motivation is that I want to show users a preview of a mesh before he can buy it. But as the JS code is viewable he could download it without paying for it. Degrading the quality of the preview mesh would be a way, but as the quality of the mesh is a selling point I would like to avoid that.

My idea was to add some kind of triangulation defects which would prevent the printing of the mesh, but which would not prevent threejs from showing the mesh.
Tools like Netfabb or Meshlab should also not be able to automatically repair the mesh.

Is there something like a bad sector copy protection equivalent for 3d models?

Comment: It would be helpful if the downvoters would give a hint how I could improve this question.

Comment: Not me. Maybe it would help if you clarify the terms. 1. "Printable" and "3D"  don't make sense when used together. 2. Triangulation tag is offtopic. 3. Does not sound like a programming question yet. 4. JS code is viewable by the client, so there's little you can do to guard it.

Comment: @Krom Stern Thank you for your hints. Tried to address those with my last edit.

Comment: Why not to present low quality mesh, like a declimated function in blender, and for printing use high poly model.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few ideas.

1) Augment your shaders to ignore some interval of vertices from the buffer (like every 3rd or something). In this way you can add "garbage" to the model file so it can not be lifted easily from the network.

2) Once in the buffer it can still be pulled out with a savvy user, unless you split the model up into many chunks and render out of order or only render the front half of the model making it less useful for 3D printing. One could also render in split views or using stereoscopic interlaced with a separation of zero.

3) Only render a none symmetrical half of your model with an camera control locked to that half :P

Kinda wonky, a ton of work to implement, and still someone will find a way I'm sure. But that's my two cents worth anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: 1) the model would still be valid regardless of whether you draw all triangles.

Comment: although you are right, it would be trick to say where it stops if the numbers are really similar

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some online shops preview with renders taken from each 10-30 degrees around the model. That way you only pass the resulting image, not the model.

Answer (score 0):

why not show a detailed HD video of your model?

Answer (score 0):

If the mesh is non-manifold it will not print.

Answer (score 0):

a) Render serverside, stream results in an interactive video

b) destroy the mesh while still keeping the normals intact for shading. You can randomly flip faces, render with double sided. You can "extrude" edges to mess up topology. As long as you map the normals correctly, it will shade without any of these defects affecting it.